# ServiceStack caching strategy

Tags: caching, servicestack

I'm learning ServiceStack and have a question about how to use the [Route] tag with caching. Here's my code:

```
[Route("/applicationusers")]
[Route("/applicationusers/{Id}")]
public class ApplicationUsers : IReturn<ApplicationUserResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public object Get(ApplicationUsers request)
{
    //var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<ApplicationUsers>("users");
    //return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, () => 

    return new ApplicationUserResponse
    {
        ApplicationUsers = (request.Id == 0)
                 ? Db.Select<ApplicationUser>()
                 : Db.Select<ApplicationUser>("Id = {0}", request.Id)
    };
}
```

What I want is for the "ApplicationUsers" collection to be cached, and the times when I pass in an Id, for it to use the main cached collection to get the individual object out.

If I uncomment the code above, the main collection is cached under the "users" key, but any specific query I submit hits the Db again. Am I just thinking about the cache wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

this line

`var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<ApplicationUsers>("users");`

is creating the same cache key for all the requests, you must use some of the request parameters to make a "unique key" for each different response.

```
var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<ApplicationUsers>(request.Id.ToString());
```

this will give you the "urn:ApplicationUsers:0" key for the get all and the "urn:ApplicationUsers:9" for the request with Id = 9

now you can use the extension method in this way.

```
 return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(Cache, cacheKey, () => {
                                                                               if(request.Id == 0) return GetAll();
                                                                               else return GetOne(request.Id);
                                                                           });
```

I hope this helps, regards.

Comment: Right, if I put a unique value in for the cacheKey, it will cache things individually. But that's not what I want. I want to cache the "All" and have the individual requests use the cached "All" collection.

Comment: In that case, keep your static cache key and filter after using the "ToOptimizedResultUsingCache" with LINQ  `      var result = RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(Cache, cacheKey, () => GetAll() );

            if( request.Id == 0 )
                return result;
            else
                return result.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == request.Id);`

Comment: I've tried that, the only problem is that "ToOptimizedResultUsingCache" returns an object and I can't cast it to my concrete type. By the time I got to this point, I started thinking that maybe I'm not using the caching as designed...

Comment: I can see, the optimize method is doing extra stuff with compression, maybe if you use the ICacheClient and store and get the List<YourResponseDto> from the cache service yourself.